# Is there a way to calculate the frequency of one word and ngrams at the same time?

Tags: r, quanteda

Right now I have two steps in my text processing using R and the package quanteda:

At the one hand I calculate the frequency of my target words for single words like citiziens.
On the other hand I calculate the frequency of ngrams.

```
txt<- "for this purpose citizens and sydney siders are the same"

tok_single<- tokens_select(tokens(txt), pattern = "citizens", padding = TRUE)
textstat_frequency(dfm(tok_single))
####bigrams
toks_bigram <- tokens_select(tokens_ngrams(tokens(txt),n=2:3), pattern = c("sydney_siders"), padding = TRUE)
                            
textstat_frequency(dfm(toks_bigram))
```

Finally I have the problem that the keywords in my dictionary consist of single words like citizens and multiple words like sydney siders. By now my calculation is done in two steps. Calculating tokens with 1-grams and n-grams separately. Is there a function to combine ngrams and 1-grams?

For example, I would like to calculate the frequency of my  dictionary items in one step.

```
mydic<-dictionary(list(citizen=c("citizen*","sydney siders","public")))
```

Comment: Yes there is. But I need to know what you are looking for. The question is stated only in the title, and only generally. From your example, what answer are you seeking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask